# moment.tz() fails when I use it in ES6/react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Why does moment-timezone fail when I use it in ES6 javascript file?

```
import moment from 'moment';
// import timezone from 'moment-timezone';

const formatTime = ({timestamp}) => {
    const formattedDT = moment.tz(timestamp, 'America/Los_Angeles').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ZZ');
    return formattedDT;
};
```

Comment: The `main` field of the `package.json` points to [`./index.js`](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/index.js) which seems to be a CommonJS file. Have you tried `const timezone = require('moment-timezone');`?

Comment: Hi Tholle, 

Thank you for replying to me. 
The main field from package.json has this:    "main": "",
Also, since I am new to react, I was not sure how I would use this timezone const?

const formatTime = ({timestamp}) => {
    const timezone = require('moment-timezone');
    const formattedDT = moment.timezone(timestamp, 'America/Los_Angeles').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ZZ');
    return formattedDT;
Is that how I would use it?

Comment: You should preferably keep all your imports and requires at the top of the file, outside of any function. You might just have to write `require('moment-timezone')`, I'm not sure how moment timezone works.

Comment: ```import moment from 'moment';
require('moment-timezone');
const formatTime = ({timestamp}) => {
    const formattedDT = moment.tz(timestamp, 'America/Los_Angeles').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ZZ');
    return formattedDT;
};
```
The require('moment-timezone') worked!! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `main` field of the `package.json` of the `moment-timezone` library points to the [`index.js`](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/index.js) file which is a CommonJS module.

It will work as expected if you require the module at the top of your file:

```
require('moment-timezone');
```

Comment: This solution is not working even i have followed above steps.

Answer (score 13):

UPD for 2018 (ES6/React), this works when using [npm version of moment-tz](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timezone)

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

moment.tz(moment.tz.guess()).zoneAbbr();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with webpack 4.

My solution was to get the correct instance of "moment".

NOTE: You must also remove any webpack loader for .json that was required in webpack 3.

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');  // import 'moment-timezone';

// once we support more regions, the timezone should be allowed to match the user's need
moment.tz.add('America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|0101|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0');
```